# Unable to Send unicode content in Jasmin SMS Gateway

Tags: php, unicode, sms, sms-gateway, jasmin-sms

I cannot send Unicode (Amharic language text) via Jasmin SMS gateway. It works for English, but not for Unicode.

```
<?php
// Sending simple message using PHP
// http://jasminsms.com

$baseurl = 'http://127.0.0.1:1401/send'

$params = '?username=foo'
$params.= '&password=bar'
$params.= '&to='.urlencode('+336222172')
$params.= '&content='.urlencode('Hello world !')

$response = file_get_contents($baseurl.$params);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

add coding=8 to your parameters. 
This is on Page 36 of the jasmin v0.9 manual
[data coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdbQj.png)

Hope it helps.